# List files in list box with no sub folder in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, directory, listbox, directory-structure

I see everyone iis trying to add their sub folders in their code. I am trying to get mine out. I have a folder I need to read from but not the sub folders within in it. I am also trying to read from two different folders into one list box. Currently in my program I have two list box's and 3 different locations. I am needing to combine two of the folders into one listbox and as I said keep the sub folders out.

```
HourlyList.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple
HourlyList.Items.Clear()
Dim directory = "C:\filepath\filepathFolder"
Dim dirinfo AS New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
list = dirinfo.GetFiles(2DArray(Row,Column) + "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
For Each file In list
    HourlyList.Items.Add(file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` if you don't want the sub-folders? You can use `EnumerateFiles` and `Concat` to get all files in both folders:

```
Dim filesFolder1 = directory1.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
Dim filesFolder2 = directory2.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

For Each file In filesFolder1.Concat(filesFolder2)
    HourlyList.Items.Add(file)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I cracked the code I belive for the sub folders but still unable to get the multiple folder into one listbox

```
HourlyList.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple
HourlyList.Items.Clear()
Dim directory = "C:\filepath\filepathFolder"
Dim dirinfo AS New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
list = dirinfo.GetFiles(2DArray(Row,Column) + "*", 
IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
For Each file In list
    HourlyList.Items.Add(file)
```